# Write a specific pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, typescript

I have an html input such as:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <label for="inputCalculator"
         class="control-label">Calculation:</label>
  <input class="form-control"
         type="text"
         [(ngModel)]="properties.calculator"
         (keyup)="onKeyUpCalculator($event.key, 0)"
         placeholder="Enter Calculator:"
         id="inputCalculator"
         name="inputCalculator"
         autocomplete="off" />
  <div *ngIf="calculatorError"
        class="alert alert-danger">
        The pattern is incorrect
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to check in the js if the input text is from this kind of pattern:

Can be X at the beginning of the string **OR** X at the beginning and after it one of the following operators: **+, -, *, /** and after the operator should have a number(**floating number as well**) and after the number an operator and after the operetor another number and so on.

Here are some examples to a valid input:

1. X
2. X*5466
3. X+2145/24525*3566
4. X-2345+31101/46704*2*2/8
5. X+4.2-43/88.33*123.11+5555

How can i write this pattern in javascript?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is it that you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: https://regex101.com will be great help

Answer (score 2):

A regex pattern that matches all those inputs is.

```
/^X((\*|\+|\/|-)\d+)*$/
```

Or shorter:

```
/^X([\*\+\/-]\d+)*$/
```

You can test it [here](http://regexr.com/3h20l).

```
^X // start with X
   ( // start a new group for all the rest
      [\*\+\/-] // one of *,+,/,-
      \d+ // at least one digit
   )* // match stuff like *123 0 or multiple times
 $ // match the end of the line
```

```js
console.log('Should match');
console.log('X is ' + isCorrect('X'));
console.log('X*5466 is' + isCorrect('X*5466'));
console.log('X+2145/24525*3566 is ' + isCorrect('X+2145/24525*3566'));
console.log('X-2345+31101/46704*2*2/8 is ' + isCorrect('X-2345+31101/46704*2*2/8'));

console.log('Should not match');
console.log('Xi is ' + isCorrect('Xi'));

function isCorrect(input) {
 return input.match(/^X([\*\+\/\-]\d+)*$/) == null ? false : true
}
```

For floating point numbers we can replace the `\d+` part of the regex with one that matches floating point numbers, like this one `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+`.

The regex would then be:

```
/^X([\*\+\/-][-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)*$/
```

Comment: Your answer look right.. But can you give some more information about it for those who aren't that.. Erghm.. Regex-pro as you are? ;)

Comment: I'm not a pro, it's really trial and error with a lot of persistance. but sure I'll add some more detailing as to what in there does what. :)

Comment: @Jordumus how about that? is that clearer? I made some small improvements to the regexes themselves too.

Comment: hm how are you testing it?

Comment: I added an example you can run, it returns null for me. which is correct since it doesn't match it.

Comment: Yep, this code works like charm. Thank u for the answer! @toskv

Comment: I added some more examples that can run ran here just to test it. If the answer fits your needs please also mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @toskv what about floating numbers? :(

Comment: just replace the part of the regex matching the digits with one capable or recognizing them. check my update.

Comment: @toskv Thank you very much for the help. 0ne last thing, can i check if i have a 0 devision? or 0.000...0 devision?

Comment: hm... it's a bit harder than I thought.. it will take more time.. I have something but it doesn't work well yet http://regexr.com/3h290 . What you can do though is just making a separate regex to only match that.